# Vue2 add class to focused input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

froI have a form with many inputs and I want to add a class to focused input label tag and remove class when another input selected.

I make such code

```
  onInputSelected: function(e) {
     var label =  e.target.previousElementSibling;
     label.classList.add('highlight');
  }
```

but how can I  remove class from one input and add to another when I change focus?

**Updated:**

I found solution but looks like it's to complicated :)

```
data: {
    allInputs: document.getElementsByTagName('input')
},
methods: {
    onInputSelected: function(e) {
        e.target.previousElementSibling.classList.add('highlight');
        [].forEach.call(this.allInputs, function (currentValue, index) {
             if(currentValue.name ==  this.name) {
                 return;
             }

              currentValue.previousElementSibling.classList.remove('highlight');
        }, e.target);
     }
}
```

Comment: You can remove class in every input then add class to targeted input.

Comment: is there something "special" you're doing with the input classes that you can't use `:focus` css selector for styling?

Comment: Yes, it can be done by css :focus selector, in my case I'm practicing Vue and trying to do such things using Vue. But looks like Vue is more data-oriented and not very suitable for such purposes. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

First of all you're not being very clear what you want to do.
2nd of all you have found solution so just clean up your code.
3rd of all I'd try using el.closest.

```
const input = document.getElementById('yourInput');
const label = input.closest("label");
// or if you want to add ids to labels
const label2 = input.closest("#yourLabel");
```

[Link to docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

With this solution you will be little bit more save. Couse in yours, lets just imagine that somebody change HTML structure... Then very high risk your code stops working.